# Circular delegation

Tags: democracy

There seems to have been 2 wallets delegating to one another at one point on the Kusama chain.

How is this possible?

I am retrieving all nested delegations and this is giving me an infinite loop in my indexer:

```
Delegation {
    id: '73',
    blockNumberStart: 9044165,
    blockNumberEnd: null,
    wallet: 'Eyd3x5a8KearHpJLw9PFgYVNDCQiTMBHSLr9yCtox2bqMFL',
    to: 'Gk1Ys5TE4uMucnVovKYNf7pzF8DVB2dyTTAWxijgXys1gDN',
    balance: 1000000000n,
    lockPeriod: 0,
    timestamp: 2021-09-02T03:22:36.004Z
  }

Delegation {
    id: '74',
    blockNumberStart: 9044201,
    blockNumberEnd: null,
    wallet: 'Gk1Ys5TE4uMucnVovKYNf7pzF8DVB2dyTTAWxijgXys1gDN',
    to: 'Eyd3x5a8KearHpJLw9PFgYVNDCQiTMBHSLr9yCtox2bqMFL',
    balance: 10000000n,
    lockPeriod: 0,
    timestamp: 2021-09-02T03:26:13.879Z
  }
```

Ey...FL delegating to GK...DN:
https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic/9044165-2

A few blocks later, GK...DN delegating to Ey...FL: https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic/9044201-3